# Create zip only with last folder

Tags: bash, zip

I am trying to create zip archive with zip tool. 
Example:

```
zip -r test.zip /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/*
```

it creates archive with directory structure exactly as in the command.
I know, that there is option -j, but it totally ignore directory structure.
In folder3 are another folders which I want in zip.
So I need something, that would do the same as

```
cd /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/
zip -r test.zip *
```

But I cant use this, because I will be using this in CGI script and I cant change folder like I want.

Thanks for advice and sorry for my english.

Comment: Re: "I will be using this in CGI script and I cant change folder like I want": That is not necessarily true. If you edit your question to include the relevant line(s) of code from your CGI script, we can show some ways that you might be able to run this one command with the desired present-working-directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create a subshell to perform the zip operation with `(cd /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/ && zip -r test.zip *)`, you can copy the files from the specified directory to the current one, select them in a `for` loop, and perform `zip -r`.

```
cp -rp /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/* .
for file in /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/*; do
echo "${file#/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/}"
done | xargs zip -r test.zip
```

Then remove them with

```
for file in /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/*; do
rm -r "${file#/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/}"
done
```

This solution presents problems if you already have folders and files with the same names in your current directory as in `/home/folder1/folder2/folder3`.

You can test if any folders/files with the same names exist beforehand with

```
for i in /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/*; do
[[ ! -e ${i#/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/} ]] || echo "$i exists"
done
```